# Compare tow fields of a list with data in mongoDb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have an in-memory list called filterProfile.

```
var filterProfile = people.Select(x => new {x.Name,x.Age}).ToList();
```

I need to run a query like this in mongodb:

```
var resultData = await collection
.Find(x => filterProfile.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Age == x.Age))
.TolistAsync();
```

using `$in` operator you can check existence of a **SINGLE** field within an array.
How can I check **TWO** fields at the same time ?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that comes to my mind is do sth like this :

```
 var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Empty;
 foreach (var item in people)
      {
         var nameFilter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Name, item.Name);
         var ageFilter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Age, item.Age);
         var loopFilter = Builders<Person>.Filter.And(nameFilter , ageFilter );
         filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Or(filter, loopFilter );
      }

var resultData = await collection.Find(filter).TolistAsync();
```

it works but looks like not so clean to me.